# Infinite potential, prevent value to go beyond zero, initial value problem

Tags: differential-equations, simulation, modeling

How do you make a wall potential in Mathematica. Meaning : I want my potential to have a wall at 0 :

$ U(x)=\left\{ \begin{split} & x>0 : U(x) = f(x)\\ &x=0: U(x)=U_0 \\ & x<0: U(x)=+\infty \\ \end{split} \right. $

Actually, it is a general question about functions with walls.

Thx in advance

Comment: Have a look at `Piecewise`.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a minimal working example of working code and data to show specifically what you are working with. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Include a minimum example of code that shows the problem and an example of the desired output.

Comment: I suggest that you delete the second part from this question and make it a new question, with proper tags and title, so you attract the attention of people with more experience in Differential equations and `NDSolveValue`.  Include exactly the message you get from mathematica. i.e *"NDSolveValue::bvdae, NDSolveValue::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems."*. I can't answer further. Probably link to the new question from here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally `NDSolve` should NOT have any problems with functions defined properly using `Piecewise`. In particular to your problem, it's impossible to comment as you have not shared your code with enough specifics.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
u[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x > 0}, {1 - x/2, x < 0}}]

Plot[
 u[x]
 , {x, -1, 1}
 , ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Blue}
 , Exclusions -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Now, if I am using NDSolve, the programm writes to me : "NDSolveValue::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems." How could I avoid that issue, given that I do not want to give initial value, but rather impose values at different points ?

Comment: @J.A In the future avoid shifting the goalpost. People feel frustrated to contribute effort to a specific question to then receive new requests not mentioned in the original question. You make the work others have done on your behalf seem irrelevant. Mma.SE is not a private consulting service but a public Q&A forum. Please, out of respect to the people trying to help you, either ask the question you need to ask properly the first time, or ask a new question, including you coded equations properly formatted. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to do better next time

Comment: @J.A We all learn something new every day. Don't feel bad, just keep trying.